# How to get fetchxml to find all account when using lt and gt and using ge & le don't work as expected

Tags: crm, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I am just starting out using fetchxml and dynamics 365 (v9)...

So, I have a dynamics 365 scheduled service that needs to be broken into smaller chunks. However, when building the fetchxml query for each schedule, I found the sums don't add up.

The entire query without the account name filtered is 1158.

But when using the conditions (below), when I add up all the result, I am still short 37 accounts.

```
<!-- this query Returns 1158 account objects. -->

<fetch distinct="true">
  <entity name="account" >
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="accountid" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="accounttype" operator="in" >
        <value>1</value>
        <value>2</value>
      </condition>
      <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="1" />
    </filter>
    <link-entity name="account" from="parentaccountid" to="accountid" link-type="inner" >
      <filter type="or" >
        <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="403310000" />
        <condition attribute="statuscode" operator="eq" value="403310007" />
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I broke up the filter to only include accounts names that start between two alphabet letters, then I repeated this until the entire alphabet was covered.

```
    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="a" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="i" />
    </filter>

    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="j" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="q" />
    </filter>

    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="r" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="z" />
    </filter>
```

Then I found I also needed to add numerals...fair enough...

```
    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="0" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="9" />
    </filter>
```

All of these queries add up to 1121, still 37 short.

So, I thought I must have made a mistake and should use 'ge' and 'le' in the filters above, I get the exact same result.

```
    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value="s1" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="s2" />
    </filter>
```

What other filters should I use to retrieve the entire set using this approach?

Shouldn't using 'less equal' and 'greater equal' work and include the current letter giving me the entire set?

EDIT 1: After Guido's suggestion:

The result is only 5 short of the total now. so close!

```
 <filter type="or" >
    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value="a" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="z" />
    </filter>
   <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value="0" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="9" />
    </filter>

    <!-- adding this extra condition almost finds the entire results 5 short -->
   <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="a" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="z" />
    </filter>

   <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value=" " />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="~" />
    </filter>
</filter>
```

Edit 2: Corrected. Thanks Guido. This works. Retrieves all accounts.

```
<filter type="or" > 
 <filter type="and" > 
  <condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="a" /> 
 </filter>

 <filter type="and" > 
  <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="a" /> 
  <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="z" /> 
 </filter> 

 <filter type="and" > 
  <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value="z" /> 
  </filter> 
</filter>
```

Next step is to break up the results into smaller chunks using this method...

Comment: I don't like this approach (gt and lt on strings) but I admit in some cases make sense. I noticed you always write to have a range (lower and higher value) did you try to make a query with just
<condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="a" />
one with
 <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="a" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="z" />
and one with
 <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value="z" />

so you cover also outside your range?

Comment: Thanks Guido, I added your suggestion (see edit 1). I'm only 5 accounts short now. Any other suggestions to retrieve the last 5.

Comment: your edit is not my suggestion. mine is:
<filter type="or" >
    <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="le" value="a" />
    </filter>
   <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="gt" value="a" />
     <condition attribute="name" operator="lt" value="z" />
    </filter>
   <filter type="and" >
     <condition attribute="name" operator="ge" value="z" />
    </filter>
</filter>

Comment: Updated my question with the corrected query. Now I need to break up into smaller results. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to break the results up into smaller chunks, I would recommend using **paging** instead.
You can add page size and page to retrieve by setting attriutes `count` and `page` on the `fetch` node of the query.

```
<fetch count='5' page='1' distinct='true' >
```

In the result you can look for attribute `morerecords` to see if you should continue querying for the next page.

Comment: Thanks, Jonas, unfortunately, we can't use paging. (we all love xrmlToolBox BTW)